# Change the text in Javascript alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change the text in a Javascript alert **after** it appeared?

For example would it be possible to create a timer inside of an alert?

```
┌────────────────────────┐
│ x seconds passed...    │
│                   <OK> │
└────────────────────────┘
```

...where `x` will be changed from `0` to passed seconds value.

I know that I can use a modal or something, but I want to know if it's possible to change the text from alert box after it appeared.

I guess it's not possible, but it's better to ask.

Comment: Nope :)  (a bunch more text here just cause I have to to post this)

Comment: I don't think you can. But fwiw, you can always override window.alert and simulate an alert prompt with some dynamically generated HTML content.

Comment: Please provide official sources...

Comment: @Johnツ: No browser allows you to style or modify its native dialogs. There usually isn't a source for things that you cannot do.

Comment: Your guess is right. It's not possible. Try using a jquery dialog/modal for custom requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of preliminary searching, it seems like it's **impossible** to do what you want. This is mainly due to security reasons, I think.

It is not recommended to use an alert box because ([WebPlatform](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/methods/alert)):

> - This is a synchronized method call. Meaning, calling this method pauses scripting execution of the window from which this method is
>     called, until the user closes the displayed dialog. Also, depending on
>     your cross tab/window usage, this can sometimes pause scripting
>     executions of other windows/tabs from the same domain.
> - Calling this method in some browsers prevents the user from interacting with the entire browser, or browser window (along with all
>     of its tabs), until the dialog is closed.
> - Intrusive dialog boxes are generally annoying for the user.

---

You could create your own dialog box using one of these:

- [jQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
- [DOMAlert](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28812/Custom-Alert-Boxes-using-JavaScript-and-the-DOM).
- [Apprise](http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-The-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery)
- [WowWindow](http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/wowwindow/)
- [YUI Simple Model Dialog](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/simpledialog-quickstart.html)

You could always have an alert that says: "Hey, look here, user, I'm trying to tell you something!" and then use one of the above.

---

Another alternative would be to create a popup using JavaScript

`window.open("http://example.com");`

or

You could use [`showModelDialog`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/methods/showModalDialog) or [`showModelessDialog`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/methods/showModelessDialog)

where you can use [`dialogArguments`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/properties/dialogArguments), [`dialogHeight`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/properties/dialogHeight), [`dialogWidth`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/properties/dialogWidth), [`dialogLeft`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/properties/dialogLeft), and [`dialogTop`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/dom/properties/dialogTop).

But the problem with that is that **most people have popup blockers** which would block your innocent popups.

---

An **ActiveX only** possibility seems to be the [Modified Alert Box](http://gotochriswest.com/development/jscript/ModifiedAlertBox/). I have not tested this as I do not have a Windows computer.

---

There also is [nsIPromptService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPromptService)'s [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPromptService#alert%28%29) and/or [`alertCheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIPromptService#alertCheck%28%29). These seem to offer more functionality such as adding a title, or a check box. There are also prompts, selections, etc.

Unfortunately, this **doesn't seem to be available in Javascript**. It seems like it's only available for firefox extensions, etc (chrome users).

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so since it is a browser generated dialog box. And for obvious security reasons, we might not have access to it

Answer (score 1):

Let's say "no". There just isn't the API to even start doing that, nor is there intended to be.

Also, JS is single-threaded & blocked during a `window.alert()` or `confirm()`. Seems pretty straight-forward that this is **provably impossible, working within the JavaScript language**.

Use a jQuery modal or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can style a modal box that looks like browser alert, and manipulate it as you want. Browser components like alert boxes are not customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to customize alert. You can try [Simple Modal dialog from YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/simpledialog-quickstart.html). You can customize it in your own way. There are also other 3rd party components available or you can make your own.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify after it is displayed. If you want this at any cost go for custom alert box solutions.